# How to fix position of numbers in an ordered list with monospace font

Tags: html, css

I have a numbered list inside of a table with monospace font and numbers in numbered list are off to the left. It seems to happen only for monospace fonts. Is there a way to make it appear on the same level as bullets on bullet list?

Simplest repro:

```
ol {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.4em;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul {
  list-style: disc;
}

table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  td {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 137px;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <ol>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
  </ol>

  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
  </ul>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ol>

        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want the numbers/bullets to not be monospaced? Do you want the beginning of the items to not align? Both of those are easily doable. If you want the browser to move the bullets to the left so that the beginning of the bullets align with the beginning of the numbers then that is more difficult but should be doable I think

Comment: @Zachiah I need numbers to be aligned the same way as bullets are on the screenshot (basically the same way as it would be aligned if there was serif font). I want it to be mono font.

Comment: If you could make a graphic showing exactly what you are hoping for that would be helpful I think

Comment: @zachiah look on the screenshot. You see green zone there? I want numbers to appear in the middle of the green zone (like it happens with non-mono fonts). Nothing else should change.

Comment: I added another option showing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a custom [`counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) that removes the trailing space that the default `counter-style: numeric` has.

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.4em;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: custom-style;
}

ul {
  list-style: disc;
}

table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  td {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 137px;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}

@counter-style custom-style {
  /* These lines just basically replicate the `counter-style: numeric` */
  system: numeric;
  symbols: "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9";

  /* This is what goes after the number */
  suffix: ".";
  /* You can imagine the default `numeric` style as */
  /* suffix: ". "; */
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ol>

        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

### Other options that produce slightly different results:

#### *Option 1:* Add space to the right of the bullet manually

The idea is to make all of the list styles have the same length of prefix since that will align them when they have monospaced font.

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.4em;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul {
  list-style: custom-style;
}

table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  td {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 137px;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}

@counter-style custom-style {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: "•";
  suffix: "  ";
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ol>

        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### *Option 2:* Make only the items monospaced (not the bullets)

This makes the `list-style` (`::marker`) parts of the elements look the same as they did in your first non-monospaced example.

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.4em;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  td {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 137px;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}

span {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li><span>Hello</span></li>
          <li><span>World</span></li>
        </ol>

        <ul>
          <li><span>Hello</span></li>
          <li><span>World</span></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### *Option 3:* Make `list-style-position: inside`

This makes the beginnings align but not the text itself.

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.4em;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  td {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 137px;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ol>

        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the opposite from what I want. I want to move numbers to the right so they will be aligned the same way as bullet list's bullets

Comment: I mean there is only one space after the numbers are you saying to just remove the space? It is monospace and the prefix looks like "1. " so the only way to really move it right would be remove the space which would make the "." touch the item. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: or did you want to move the text next to the numbers to the right as well? That's similar to option 3 if so, although you could do it with the list-style as well if you prefixed the items with a space I suppose

Comment: Option #4 is what I need. Do you mind making another answer with this option only so I can mark it as correct? Also I'm wondering how does it work?

Comment: I just edited this answer to only have the 4th option and I added more detail. I commented the code as well to show what is happening in a bit more detail. Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: @EugeneTsakh I discussed the whole removing the other options thing in a chat and have decided to add them back for posterity. I'll be sure to put your preferred answer on top though

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ol > li::marker {
  white-space: inherit;
}
```

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.4em;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ol > li::marker {
  white-space: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  td {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 137px;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ol>

        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>World</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker)

Comment: I added a stack snippet so we can see what it's doing. It doesn't seem to be doing much. Feel free to edit it if I did something wrong

Comment: @Zachiah Open dev tools and toggle the property that Renato added to see what it's doing.

Comment: Yeah I mean it's literally doing nothing as far as I can tell

Comment: Tks guys. My suggestion doesn't really works on all browsers. I noticed this reading your comments. Only works on Firefox.

Comment: @Zachiah It's removing the space between the period and the list-item content, which is what OP asked for.

Comment: I can confirm it works on firefox. I was using Arc (a chromium based browser) so it wasn't working.